# Accessing env variables inside vite.config

Tags: vite

I'm trying to set a different input HTML based on the environment I'm running for, however when running `tsc && vite build --mode staging` with the following vite.config

```
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode, ssrBuild }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');
  return {
    base: env.BASE_PATH,
    plugins: [
      react({

      })
    ],
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        input: {
          main: (env.MODE == "staging" ? resolve(__dirname, 'staging.html') : resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'))
        }
      }
    },
  }
})
```

It's still rendering index.html, and the base path is still the default.

According to [the documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config) what I've done should work, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Normal enviornment variables live in `process.env`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to add `MODE` variable in `.env` file. Likes:

```
MODE="stagging"
```